# Python/Numpy: Perform an np.all equivalent to different columns for each row

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, boolean

I am looking for a vectorized and memory efficient solution to apply the equivalent of `np.all` to each row of a 3-d numpy array, where for each row a different set of columns are `np.all`'d together. For each row, the columns to apply `np.all` to are identified by a second array.

The array to perform the operation on is `dataArr`, a 3-d numpy boolean array of shape (5, 3, 5).

```
dataArr = np.array([  
                    [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]],
                    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]],
                    [[1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
                    [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]], 
                    [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
])
```

The array containing the data identifying the columns to include in the `np.all` operation (or equivalent) to each row in `dataArr` is called `relCols`, a 2-d numpy boolean array of shape (5, 3) with the same number of rows and cols as `dataArr`. The values in each row indicate which columns in the corresponding row of `dataArr` to apply `np.all` to.

```
relCols = np.array([
                    [1, 0, 1],      #apply equivalent of np.all to dataArr[0,(0,2)]
                    [0, 1, 1],      #apply equivalent of np.all to dataArr[1,(1,2)]
                    [1, 1, 0],      #apply equivalent of np.all to dataArr[2,(0,1)]
                    [1, 0, 1],      #apply equivalent of np.all to dataArr[3,(0,2)]
                    [0, 1, 1]       #apply equivalent of np.all to dataArr[4,(1,2)]
])
```

This is a simplified version of my application, where dataArr is MUCH larger so I am looking for a fully vectorized approach if that is possible.

What I currently do is use np.ones for the irrelevant columns in dataArr and use `np.all(dataArr, axis=1)`. While this works, it adds significant unnecessary memory overhead which is what I am trying to alleviate.

**Desired result:**

```
result = np.array([  
                    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is some sample code showing in effect my original approach. The `dataArr` has been resized to mimick what I may encounter. `np.ones` is not explicitly used below but the irrelevant columns containing zeros have been replaced with ones.

```
def original():

    dataArr = np.array([  
                        [[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]],
                        [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]],
                        [[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
                        [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]], 
                        [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]]
    ], dtype=bool)

    dataArr = np.repeat(dataArr,200000, axis=0); 
    dataArr = np.repeat(dataArr,100, axis=2);   #resulting shape = (1000000, 3, 1000)

    dataReduced = np.all(dataArr, axis=1)
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your output. How do you get a `(5, 5)` array? Can you explain how you arrive at `[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]` in the first row? I'm reading `dataArr[0, (0, 2)]` as the first subarray in `dataArr`, with `np.all()` on columns 0 and 2. But that would just give two values, both zero if evaluated over axis 1, but only one value if evaluated normally.

Comment: If you replace all the columns containing `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` with `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` and performed `np.all(dataArr, axis=1)` you would get the `(5, 5)` array shown in my result. I'm trying to replicate that without setting the irrelevant columns to ones.

`[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]` is the result of evaluating whether the elements along axis 0 in columns 0 and 2 are all true. So, its where `[1, 1, 1, 0, 1]` (row 0, col 0) and `[1, 1, 1, 1, 0]` (row 0, col 2) are both true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try working with masked arrays. More details in [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) -

1. First create a mask with `np.ones_like` and subtracting the broadcasted `relCols` by adding an axis to it.
2. Next, create a masked array from the `dataArr`
3. Use `np.all` over axis=1 which computes the operation on the non-masked values and ignores the masked ones.

```
mask = np.ones_like(dataArr) - relCols[...,None]
maskedArr = np.ma.MaskedArray(dataArr, mask)
np.all(maskedArr, axis=1).astype(int).data
```

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test this out and see if it is less memory intensive than my original approach of using np.ones for irrelevant columns

Comment: it would be great if you could add your initial approach with full code so I could do some benchmarking as well. thanks!

Comment: @CraigNathan at the very least use `"uint8"` or `"int8"` for your ones array!

Comment: Thats a great point @ddejohn, specially if memory is the core issue here.

Comment: Thank you both. I added what effectively is how my original code works to allow for some benchmarking